# Bluetooth binary communication losed bytes

Tags: bluetooth, frame, truncated, pic32

I work on a bluetooth communication between samsung Galaxy tab and a custom device.

On the custom device there is a PIC32 (Microchip) and a bluetooth RN-42. The communication between the PIC and RN-42 is serial (UART).

When I use text protocol all is working fine but with binary protocol the frame sent by the custom device are truncated (8 bytes are missing).

If I add 8 bytes at the end of the frame, complete answer is received by the client.

I have made some tests with several clients (Galxy tab, macbook...) and the result is the same.

I have verified on debug mode than all bytes are sent by the PIC32.

Is someone has encountered this kind of problem ? Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the PIC UART configuration.

I have added this line and now it works.
UARTSetFifoMode(UART2, UART_INTERRUPT_ON_TX_NOT_FULL | UART_INTERRUPT_ON_RX_NOT_EMPTY);